# How to add text on gstreamer except textoverlay?

Tags: c, linux, overlay, gstreamer, cpu-usage

I'm using textoverlay to add dynamic text in GStreamer. But the problem is it takes quite lot of CPU usage.
Assume that, I only record video --> CPU usage about 3-5 %. But when I add textoverlay, It can reached up to 20% at peak.

This is my pipeline:

> source -> overlay -> frameratefilter -> encoder -> h264parse ->
> splitmuxsink

This is how I add dynamic text:

```
gboolean timeout_callback(gpointer data){
  g_object_set (overlay, "text", v_overlay, NULL);
}
...
g_timeout_add_seconds_full (G_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 1 , timeout_callback , loop, NULL);
```

So, is there any way to add dynamic text in GStreamer without using textoverlay ? Or, there is a problem with the way I do dynamic text ?

Please help me !

[UPDATED] For more info, I'm using splitmuxsink to write video.

Comment: Thats very little context about your main pipeline.

Comment: I added more details. Please help me ! If It's not enough, please tell me what info you need.

Comment: What kind of encoder.. how big is the area you draw with text? VRAM or Host memory? You description does not any of these questions. Note that drawing text is a pixel operation and can be expensive.

Comment: I'm using iMX6Solo of NXP. So I'm using vpuenc_h264 encoder. I draw 4 line (each line contain 1 variable which change every second) with font-desc=Sans 6 and all in 1 element textoverlay. I run top command and get 3% of RAM per 512 MB.

Comment: Right.. so i don\t know how powerful the the host CPU is on this device. If the pipeline without the overlay is on GPU space this will involve a memory round-trip from GPU to host and back to GPU. So i can imagine rendering from some font and writing it to a GPU designated buffer to be somewhat expensive.

Comment: So what can I do to reduce CPU usage in this case ? I very interesting to hear the answer from you !